# how to process(add all values in a column) a queryset while using django-filters

Tags: python, django, django-filter

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters
from adfilters.models import Product
from django.contrib import admin

class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
   price = NumberFilter(lookup_type = 'lte')
   description=CharFilter()
   release_date=DateRangeFilter()
   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = {'price':['lte','gte'] }
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from adfilters.filters import ProductFilter,DateRangeFilter
from .models import Product
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext,loader
#from crm.search import *
from mysite.search import *
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url

import django_filters

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")

def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    fd = DateRangeFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
```

These are my models,views and filter.py files.

I want to get total of prices of a particular filter criteria.

Suppose I search for *records price>12* and I get *3 records.* I need to know the total of all prices for the displayed records.

How can I process such manipulations while using django-filters?